# Custom update query for doctrine model field

Tags: php, mysql, concurrency, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a Doctrine model that I would like to protect using optimistic locking. The version field I am using is a `DateTime` - unfortunately, because this is only precise to the second, the built-in Doctrine versioning does not work if multiple queries are executed at the same second.

To fix this, I have created a query that uses `NOW(6)`, which has microsecond precision:

```sql
UPDATE thing
SET count = count + 1, modified_at = NOW(6)
WHERE modified_at = ?
```

I would like this query to be used when I call `$thing_repository->save($thing)`. How can I register a custom update query (or function) to be called when the entity is saved, instead of the built-in `persister->update($entity)`?